# How to store paths in configuration file in netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans, path

I have a java project in netBeans that deals with some paths in order to be able to work. It is headache to change the paths every time that you are run it on other machine. Thus, I am wondering if there is a way that help me to come over this issue. One suggested to me to use configuration file, but I don't have any idea about how to do it. So, kindly could you help me in this, please?

Comment: write a class that parses a text file for `key = value` pairs

Comment: It's unclear what paths are you talking about. Data files paths?

Comment: @HEKTO I meant the path of my files yes.

Comment: Make a `Properties` class and populate it with static members, read the properties file and store data in the static strings. Then access by something like `somePath = Properties.PATH_TO_FILES`

Comment: Are those paths needed at compile time or at runtime?

Comment: @redFIVE thank you for the clarification, I will shift to this method if I failed to use configuration file

Comment: @AlexS both compile and run time

Comment: @Programer14, that is for a configuration file. You populate the static members from the stuff read from the config file. This is a standard way of doing things.

Comment: @redFIVE Amazing! I like it, it will be a great if you guide me to an example that it does it after making the configuration file. Appreciate your help

Comment: @Programer14, www.google.com

Comment: http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-properties-file-examples/ This link helped me, I put it here for future reference. @redFIVE Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have the Ant target *run* in your `build.xml` file. In most cases this target contains only one *task* - the `java` task. You can add **arg** elements to this task. One of possible types of these elements is `file`. So, your target will look like this:

```
<target name="run" depends="build">
  <java classpath="${basedir}" classname="..." fork="yes">
    <jvmarg value="-enableassertions"></jvmarg>
    <arg file="abc.txt"/>
    <arg file="def.txt"/>
  </java>
</target>
```

The Java interpreter will look for files `abc.txt` and `def.txt` in the base directory of your project. So, if you run the NetBeans on different machines, then it will be enough to have your data files in this directory. Of course, it's not only possibility - the Ant `build.xml` file is flexible enough to define any location you want.

As for more info about Ant - http://ant.apache.org/manual/using.html#arg

**ADDITION:**

The filenames, defined via `arg` elements in the `build.xml` file, will be accessible from Java code via the `main` function argument array. So, the program:

```
public static void main(String ARG[])
{
  for (String s: ARG) System.out.println(s);
}
```

will print:

```
<your absolute project directory>/abc.txt
<your absolute project directory>/def.txt
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it seems helpful. I will try it.

Comment: Could you tell me how to use it inside my program?? Outside the main. I think we should use args but how?

Comment: I have to change classpath or keep it as it is??

Comment: I'll make additions to my answer

Comment: The classpath doesn't need to be changed

Comment: Thank you for your effoets, but is there is a way that I can use it without having the main method??

Comment: Yes, of course you can read paths to all your files from a single configuration file - as was suggested in other comments. The standard library class, which is good for this purpose, is `java.util.Properties`